# Jpa Syntax Error Parsing

Tags: java, sql, jpa

```
    EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence
            .createEntityManagerFactory("PrimeEclipseLink");
    EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory
            .createEntityManager();
    Query query=entityManager.createQuery("select name from member");
    List<String> memberList=query.getResultList();
    for(String e:memberList){
        System.out.println(e);
```

I want list name in my database but I get error message like this.`

```
Tem 14, 2015 9:55:28 AM com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase  execute
WARNING: #{memberControl.login()}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An exception occurred while creating a query in EntityManager: 
Exception Description: Syntax error parsing [select name from member]. 
[23, 23] An identification variable must be provided for a range variable declaration.
javax.faces.FacesException: #{memberControl.login()}:  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An exception occurred while creating a query    in EntityManager: 
Exception Description: Syntax error parsing [select name from member]. 
[23, 23] An identification variable must be provided for a range variable declaration.
```

Comment: Try to use `createNativeQuery` instead of `createQuery`?

Comment: why would he use SQL? That is easily expressable using JPQL. Just put an alias on the end ... "SELECT m.name FROM member m"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `createNativeQuery` instead of `createQuery` in following:

`Query query=entityManager.createNativeQuery("select name from member");`

Answer (score 2):

Your JPQL query is invalid as the message says. Just change your JPQL query to be

```
SELECT m.name FROM member m
```

and then it would work (since that is valid JPQL). 
The other answer would mean you throw away datastore independence.